# Where do I put WHERE command on complex sql command

Tags: sql, asp.net, oracle

Database admin sent me sql command for my asp.net project. But it's so hard to understand for me.

Command:

```
SELECT to_char(FirstDate, 'yyyymmdd') AS EXPR1, SUM(Single) AS SingleFile, SUM(Sum) AS AllFiles ROUND(SUM(SingleSize) / (1024 * 1024 * 1024), 2) AS SingleSize,
            ROUND(SUM(SumSize)/(1024 * 1024 * 1024), 2) AS SumSize
FROM (SELECT FILE, MIN(DATE) AS FirstDate, 1 AS Single, COUNT(*) AS Sum, MAX(Size) AS SingleSize, SUM(Size) AS SumSize
            FROM INETISLE.XFERLOG
            GROUP BY FILE) derivedtbl_1
GROUP BY to char(FirstDate,'yyyymmdd')
ORDER BY 1
```

Output like this:

```
EXPR1       SingleFile      SumFile         SingleSize     SumSize
19.11.2014  123123          13423           12312423       23424132
```

I need to link EXPR1(date) to my calendar.

Asp.net calendar control added WHERE like this:

```
WHERE ([EXPR1] = ?)
```

Where do I put this WHERE on my complex sql command?

I need to select just one day that I select on Calendar.

Comment: Between a FROM and GROUP BY, so there are two plcaes where you could add a where.

Comment: Where are you getting EXPR1 in your query?

Comment: I don't see EXPR1 at all in the query you gave us.  Where does that come from?

Comment: Could you translate your column names into english for us? May be easier for some of us to understand :) I'm guessing DOSYA is day?

Comment: Sorry, edited for EXPR1. I will edit for translate to English.

Comment: Translated column names.

Comment: Try putting your where clause before the line "GROUP BY to char(FirstDate,'yyyymmdd')" , but I think it needs to be where FirstDate = , rather than EXPR1 , you cant use an alias in this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT to_char(IlkTarih, 'yyyymmdd') AS EXPR1, SUM(Toplam) AS ToplamDosya,     ROUND(SUM(TekilBoyut) / (1024 * 1024 * 1024), 2) AS TekilBoyut,
            ROUND(SUM(ToplamBoyut)/(1024 * 1024 * 1024), 2) AS ToplamBoyut
FROM (SELECT DOSYA, MIN(TARIH) AS IlkTarih, 1 AS Tekil, COUNT(*) AS Toplam, MAX(BOYUT) AS TekilBoyut, SUM(BOYUT) AS ToplamBoyut
            FROM INETISLE.XFERLOG
            WHERE DATE(TARIH) = ?
            GROUP BY DOSYA) derivedtbl_1
GROUP BY to char(IlkTarih,'yyyymmdd')
ORDER BY 1
```

Comment: Thanks but getting error: ora-00936: missing expression.